# How to align subgraph clusters vertically in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Does anybody know how to align these subgraphs vertically?

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=record, style=rounded, fontname="Arial"];
  subgraph cluster1 {
    label = "Group 1";
    rank=same;
    A [label="A1|A2"]
    A -> B -> C -> D [constraint=false];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  subgraph cluster2 {
    label = "Group 2";
    rank=same;
    Z -> Y -> X -> W [dir=back, constraint=false];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  D -> Z;
}
```

I'd like to shift up Group 2 to the center of Group 1.
[image]

Almost did that with this code, but it is still not aligned a bit:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR;
  node [shape=record, style=rounded, fontname="Arial"];

  subgraph cluster1 {
    group=g1;
    label = "Group 1";
    rank=same;
    A [label="A1|A2"];
    A -> B -> C -> D [constraint=false];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  subgraph cluster2 {
    group=g2;
    label = "Group 2";
    rank=same;
    Z -> Y -> X -> W [dir=back, constraint=false];
    style = "dashed";
  }

  D -> Z;

  edge[style=invis];
  A -> Z;
  D -> W;
}
```

Group 2 should be shifted up to the center.
[image]